# Как клонировать git без использования пароля?

Tags: git

`Git` расположен на своем сервере (сервер на `beget`), есть следующие данные:

`username` - логин от `FTP` (включена поддержка `ssh`, корневой доступ)
`password` - пароль
`myserver.beget.tech` - адрес сервера
`git/public_html/git` - папка с репозиторием в корне сервера

Устанавливаю адрес для подключения к удаленному репозиторию так:

```
git remote set-url origin username@myserver.beget.tech:git/public_html/git
```

Клонирую репозиторий на локальный компьютер так:

```
git clone username@myserver.beget.tech:git/public_html/git
```

Все нормально, подключение и клонирование проходят успешно, однако, в консоль постоянно требуется вводить пароль. Для настройки доступа без пароля воспользовался `RSA`-ключами, при подключении через `PuTTY` указал файл с приватным ключом, и программа подключается без пароля.

Интересует вопрос: как дать возможность подключения без пароля при помощи обычной консоли `Windows` (ведь при помощи нее я клонирую репозиторий на локальный компьютер).

Answer (score 2):

Также как в Linxu с ssh. Закрытый ключ должен лежать в `~/.ssh/id_rsa` или в более привычной для пользователей Windows форме - в `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa`